# (Matlab) MovieWriter generates Black White movie from Color Images

Tags: image, matlab, video

I want to generate a movie from an image sequence. I used this code:

```
%% 4.) GENERATE THE MOVIE
disp("Generate the Movie...");
imageNames = dir(fullfile('images','*.png'));
imageNames = {imageNames.name}';
outputVideo = VideoWriter(fullfile('images','AcousticCamera.mp4'),'MPEG-4');
outputVideo.FrameRate = 10;
outputVideo.Quality = 95;
open(outputVideo)
for ii = 1:length(imageNames) %% loop over the images
   img = imread(fullfile('images',imageNames{ii}));
   writeVideo(outputVideo,img)
end
close(outputVideo)
```

The input images are png color images but the video is black white.

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't add a profile, it defaults to grayscale.
[Videowriter Documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter.htm)

Comment: I added a profile  to the VideoWriter obejct, but it is not supportet, perhaps because the mp4. I got --> Unrecognized method, property, or field 'colormap' for class 'VideoWriter'.

Comment: Try `profiles = VideoWriter.getProfiles()` and see if you even have MPEG-4 available.

Comment: ProfileInfo Properties:

       Name:                     'MPEG-4'
       Description:              'A MPEG-4 file with H.264 Compression'
       FileExtensions:           {'.mp4' '.m4v'}
       ColorChannels:            3
       FrameRate:                30
       Quality:                  75
       VideoBitsPerPixel:        24
       VideoCompressionMethod:   'H.264'
       VideoFormat:              'RGB24'

Comment: I think i must add the colormap to the imb object, because this is an ordinary uint8 matrice and has only grayscale information.

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution:

```
...
colorMap = jet(256);
for ii = 1:length(imageNames) %% loop over the images
   img = imread(fullfile('images',imageNames{ii}));
   writeVideo(outputVideo,im2frame(img,colorMap))
end
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.